# Keeping ASP.Net TreeView nodes collapsed when navigating web site

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, treeview, nodes

I noticed that when navigating an ASP.Net web site the nodes in the TreeView always expand.

Is there a setting or attribute we can include in the markup that will keep the TreeView nodes collapsed until the user expands them?

Maybe something is needed to be added to the code-behind file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is, it's called [ExpandDepth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.expanddepth.aspx)

ExpandDepth - Gets or sets the number of levels that are expanded when a TreeView control is displayed for the first time.

If you want all the nodes, including the root, to be collapsed just set it to 0

```
<asp:TreeView ExpandDepth="0" ...
```

Comment: Thanks Deni. It's just what we needed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this in the markup. But it is possible in code - behind. Check out this link for some sample code: [Collapse all open nodes](http://www.devcurry.com/2009/05/collapse-all-open-nodes-of-aspnet.html).

I'm pretty sure that an app I wrote a few years collapses the entire tree with one line of code (like you we found that it kept opening up every post back). If this link doesn't work I will post the code I used tomorrow.

The one line of code I was looking for is

```
tv.CollapseAll();
```

Comment: Thanks markp3rry for the helpful reply. For now we will be using ExpandDepth="0" but will be implementing code similar to your link when we want more control of the TreeView.